# CSS Modules composes not working

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, postcss, css-modules

I'm trying to setup css modules with postcss + cssnext. It all seems to be working fine, except that the `composes` keyword is simply not working. The rule vanishes when the bundle is compiled.

Here's my webpack config file:

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    plugins: [
        // new DashboardPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new HtmlPlugin({
            title: 'Github App',
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'html', 'template-dev.html')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /src/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /src/,
            use: ['style-loader', {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            }, {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    ident: 'postcss'
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            Components: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'components')
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using style-loader for this dev environment so I can use hot reloading. The css file is being imported like this: `import './app.css'`
app.css:

```
:global{
    .app {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.className {
    color: green;
    background: red;
}

.otherClassName{
    composes: className;
    color: yellow;
}
```

this results in:

[image]

My `postcss.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'postcss-cssnext': {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%']
        },
        'postcss-nested': {}
    }
}
```

Am I missing something to get `composes` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is fine: 
The implementation of webpack's css_loader is to add both classes when exporting the styles (see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#composing)

This also makes more sense, since it will ultimately render out less CSS code.
Try importing the styles and apply them to an HTML node and you will see it should receive both classes.

In your example it would have done something like:

```
exports.locals = {
  className: 'className-2yqlI',
  otherClassName: 'className-2yqlI otherClassName-1qAvb'
}
```

So when you do:

```
import styles from '../app.css'

// ...

<div className={styles.otherClassName} />
```

The div gets both classes.

Comment: Ohh I understand now. I was hoping that it'd work like SASS extend, but looks like composes only makes sense when actually using the class. Thanks